# Protractor IF condition was executed first before IT

Tags: jasmine, protractor

Is there a way to ensure that `it` will be executed first before the `if` condition located below it?

Sample Code:

```
it('should click ' + strName + ' from the list', function() {
    exports.waitForElementDisp(10, global.elmGravityPanel, false);
    browser.sleep(2000).then(function() {
        element(by.css('[cellvalue="' + strName + '"]')).click();
        element(by.id('uniqueid')).getText().then(function(tmpText) {
            global.tempObject.isPresent = false;
            if (tmpText == strName) {
                global.tempObject.isPresent = true;
            }
        });
    });
});

if (global.tempObject.isPresent == true) {
    it('should click the settings icon', function() {
        global.elmSettingBtn.click();
    });

    it...
}
```

Currently, global.tempObject.isPresent was set to null and protractor did not go inside the IF even though it will be set as true inside the first IT.

Comment: Wrap the if condition inside a browser.call()...http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.call

Comment: Thats a control flow issue

Comment: @Grasshopper you mean, browser.call(if (condition) {...})?

Comment: Place the if condition inside a function. And function inside browser.call. browser.call(function(){if.........})

Answer (score 0):

Because this 'if' is executed on file parsing.
I would suggest to try something like this:

```
it(`should click ${strName} from the list`, function () {
    exports.waitForElementDisp(10, global.elmGravityPanel, false);
    browser.sleep(2000)
    $(`[cellvalue="${strName}"]`).click();
    $('#uniqueid').getText().then(function (tmpText) {
        global.tempObject.isPresent = false;
        if (tmpText == strName) {
            global.tempObject.isPresent = true;
        }
    });

});

/**
 * 
 * @param condition Any boolean condition to check
 * @param suiteOrTest function, that contains scheduling of tests.
 */
function runIf(condition, suiteOrTest) {
    if (condition) {
        return suiteOrTest
    } else {
        console.log('Skipping execution')
    }
}

describe('Conditional execution', () => {
    it('1', function () {
        global.elmSettingBtn.click();
    });

    it('This test is with condition', runIf(process.env.IS_LINUX, ()=> {
        // Some other test
        global.elmSettingBtn.click();
    }))
}))
```

Comment: hi, I got an error stating "ReferenceError: decribe is not defined" do I need to update anything on the line of describe?
I pasted the line as is and got the error.

Comment: oh the spelling is wrong. after updating a different error appears
- TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: sorry, tried this. Now should be fine. Check the code again or here is example: https://github.com/Xotabu4/Protractor-Experiments/blob/master/experiments/conditionalJasmine/experiment.ts

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a fan of wrapping the `it` block in a conditional. So below are my thoughts of how you would change your code to avoid using the conditional around the `it` block.

- If you are expecting the unique text to appear on the element for the following `it` block, you could increase the browser wait for the expected conditions that element appears instead of having an arbitrary sleep time. After the element is available we could then do some checks against the text.
- If you have a mixture of workflows that sometimes test to see if a unique text is present and other times where the unique tests is not present, I would then split that out into two different workflows.
- If the element is not there, we could fail the tests after that based on the `uniqueText` not being present. This could be overkill.

---

```
  let EC = ExpectedConditions;
  let button = element(by.css('[cellvalue="' + strName + '"]'));
  let uniqueText = element(by.id('uniqueid'));

  // your locator strategy here.
  let elemSettingBtn = element(by.css('something')); 

  it('should click ' + strName + ' from the list', function() {
    // Leaving this line alone. Not sure what this is doing.
    exports.waitForElementDisp(10, global.elmGravityPanel, false);      

    browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(button), 3000);
    button.click();

    browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(uniqueText), 3000);
    expect(uniqueText.getText()).toEqual(strName);
  });

  it('should click the settings icon', function() {
    uniqueText.isPresent().then(present => {
      if (present) {
        // click the settings button because the unique text is there.
        return elmSettingBtn.click();
      } else { 
        // Maybe fail the test when the button is not present?
        fail('unique text is not present.');
      }          
    });
  });
```